# Можно ли в Unity в EditorWindow/CustomEditor динамически создать экземпляр класса и присвоить его переменной?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Суть проблемы: есть сериализуемый класс-родитель, LevelBuilder, есть несколько потомков - LivingDungeon, BSPDungeon etc. Необходимо с помощью кнопки или печеречисления в окне редактора присвоить переменной LevelBuilder builder (в scriptableObject) = new LivingDungeon(); Так, чтобы в окне редактора отображались и свойства базового класса, и свойства потомка.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите сохранять в scriptableObject данные производного класса по ссылке базового. Проблема заключается в том что Unity не поддерживает встроенную полиморфную сериализацию. По ссылке на базовый класс Unity сериализует только данные базового класса.

На сколько мне известно, эту проблему можно решить с помощью жудких костылей.